# Paypal checkout - trouble for going live

Tags: php, paypal, checkout, live

I am making a payment page with paypal checkout (in php), everything is working fine when i am in sandbox mode but when i go live, i got this error after paying...

`Fatal error: Uncaught PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException: Got Http response code 401 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token. in www/src/package/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php:207`
`Stack trace: #0 www/src/package/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Auth/OAuthTokenCredential.php(252): PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('grant_type=clie...')` `#1 www/src/package/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Auth/OAuthTokenCredential.php(280): PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential->getToken(Array, 'qsdqsdqsdqsd', 'qdsqdsdqsdsqd', 'grant_type=clie...')` `#2 www/src/package/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Auth/OAuthTokenCredential.php(216): PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential->generateAccessToken(Array, NULL)` `#3 www/src/package/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Auth/OAuthTokenCredential.php(166): PayPal\Auth\OAuthTokenCredential->updateAccessToken(Array)` `#4 www/src/package/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php on line 207`

Could you help me ?
Thanks

Comment: `Got Http response code 401 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com` the error indicates that you still working with the sandbox version of paypal. Make sure you changed everything from the sandbox version to the live version.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, it appears you changed your credentials to live without changing the environment from sandbox to live, so those live credentials are being used against a sandbox endpoint, which won't work. The two environments are completely separate.

Also, it appears you are using the deprecated v1/payments SDK, for which there is no support. You should change your integration to the current v2/checkout/orders Checkout-PHP-SDK...

Make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). The latter one should (on success) store the payment details in your database before it does the return (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID)

Pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server